# Discriminant of a cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> If $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, prove that:
>   $$d(1, \zeta,...,\zeta^{\varphi(n)-1})=(-1)^{\varphi(n)/2}n^{\varphi(n)}\prod_{p\mid n} p^{-\frac{\varphi(n)}{p-1}}$$

Let $n=\prod_{i=1}^{m}p_i^{e_i}$. After looking it up in some books, I was able to understand why this is true for $m=1$. However, they all ignored the general case $m>1$ or simply stated that it could be done by induction on $m$, but I really can't see how it could be done.

The only interesting thing I could find out was that for $n,m$ with $\gcd(n, m)=1$, we get, on the right hand side of the equation:

$$(-1)^{\varphi(nm)/2}nm^{\varphi(nm)}\prod_{p\mid nm} p^{-\frac{\varphi(nm)}{p-1}}=$$
$$\left((-1)^{\varphi(n)/2}n^{\varphi(n)}\prod_{p\mid n} p^{-\frac{\varphi(n)}{p-1}}\right)^{\varphi(m)}\left((-1)^{\varphi(m)/2}n^{\varphi(m)}\prod_{p\mid m} p^{-\frac{\varphi(m)}{p-1}}\right)^{\varphi(n)}$$

That makes me think I'm getting somewhere, but I'm stuck with the problem of showing that $d(1, \zeta,...,\zeta^{\varphi(nm)-1})=[d(1, \zeta,...,\zeta^{\varphi(n)-1})]^{\varphi(m)}[d(1, \zeta,...,\zeta^{\varphi(m)-1})]^{\varphi(n)}$, which doesn't seem trivial at all. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can find a detailed calculation in Cassels-Fröhlich's book, chapter III by Birch, lemma 6

Comment: I also have the impression that Washington's GTM book "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields" talked about these basics in the very beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because we have a proposition that says 
If $K, F$ are two number fields  linearly disjoint over $\mathbb{Q}$,
$KF$ their compositum, and their discriminants are coprime. then

$$\delta_{KL}=\delta_{K}^{[L:\mathbb{Q}]}\cdot\delta_{L}^{[K:\mathbb{Q}]}$$ 
and in our case we have $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m})$ are linearly disjoint because $ gcd(n,m)=1$ , and their discriminants are coprime
then 
$$\delta_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{mn})}=\delta_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})}^{\phi(m)}\cdot\delta_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m})}^{\phi(n)}$$.

But the problem is $$\bigg( (-1)^{\phi(n)/2}n^{\phi(n)}\prod_{p\mid n}p^{\frac{-\phi(n)}{p-1}}\bigg)^{\phi(m)}\cdot\bigg( (-1)^{\phi(m)/2}n^{\phi(m)}\prod_{p\mid m}p^{\frac{-\phi(m)}{p-1}}\bigg)^{\phi(n)}=(-1)^{\phi(nm)}(nm)^{\phi(nm)}\prod_{p\mid nm}p^{\frac{-\phi(nm)}{p-1}}$$